# Calling function with no return value from getElementById().innerHTML ??? Is it possible ? how?

Tags: javascript, html

Hi great coding community,

I was struggling here for the whole weekend with this question in my head. I am trying to call a function within document.getElementBy... element but I am still getting undefined output. Well, I got the output from the function, but only if I put there a return value into the LoginFunction(). Otherwise only undefined.

But problem is, that this function is not returning anything. I'm just creating the buttons with it. (Maybe it should return something, but I designed it so poorly :D)

Anyway, my aim is to create a buttons into newly created div tag. I know that with return value (at least with simple text) it works. I got text within the new div. But without return value, nothing happened. And I tried these options:

// creating div, with id or with class - doesnt matter.

```
global_div = document.createElement("div");
```

// global_div.classList.add("two");

```
global_div.id = "two";
```

// appending it into the body.

```
document.body.appendChild(global_div);
```

// now calling the function:

```
document.getElementById('two').innerHTML = LoginFunction();
document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].innerHTML = LoginFunction();
document.getElementById('two').call = LoginFunction();
document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].call = LoginFunction();
document.getElementById('two').innerText...    
document.body.appendChild(global_div);
```

and other options, versions, combinations... nothing helped.
The LoginFunction() is:

```
function LoginFunction() {
    console.log("LoginFunction called")
    var myLoop_var;
    let outcome;
    
    <!-- START BUTTON -->
    
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.innerHTML = "START";
    btn.id = "start";
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
        btn.disabled = true;
        btn2.disabled = false;
        console.log("START BUTTON clicked");
        clearInterval(global_var);
        global_var = setInterval(function(){myLoop()}, 1000);
        console.log('MY LOOP VAR: ', global_var);
    });
}
```

There are two other buttons with more less same code. So I am waiting for the click on the buttons. So basically they are not returning anything.

And in short, I want to click on one button which create a three new buttons in one div. Then, when I click on the same button, all three buttons are removed together with created div.

I would be really appreciating if somebody could give me a hint or lead me on the right way with this.

Many thanks to all of you. :)

ok sorry, that's my poor explanation skill as well. Pictures maybe helped more.

This is start:

[image]

This is after buttons are created:
[image]

And my dreamed result:

```
<div id="two">
<button id="start">START</button>
<button id="stop" disabled="">STOP</button>
<button id="stop" disabled="">STOP</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it makes no sense to assign the value `undefined` (which will become the string `"undefined"`) to `innerHTML` - I can't see what you're even trying to do with that function to be honest, and why you'd want to run it 4 times

Comment: There is no `return` statement in `LoginFunction()`, therefore it implicitly produces `undefined`. If you want it to produce any other value, add a `return` statement. It's not really clear what you expect the result to be, though.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not call function with innerHTML as you are doing.

As per your way, innerHTML means you need to provide whole HTML string with all three buttons inclued which should be returned by function.
e.g

```
Elem.innerHTML = func()
func(){
  return "<HTML string with all buttons tag />"
}
```

Another way, when you click on button, just call your function which perform adding of all buttons in parent div and append it, so you won;t bother about innerHTML or return values.
e.g

```
onclick="func()"
func(){
  div_elem.append(buttons) // on innerHTML
}
```

Comment: Hi Piyush Goyani, I did it via the onclick as you suggested. It looks like that it's working via onclick. I could also add a decision function as I wanted to run more functions under this click. Many thanks. :)